# Do I need to use 'new' operator when creating instance of Immutable.Record?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

example from docs *https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record*

```
var ABRecord = Record({a:1, b:2})
var myRecord = new ABRecord({b:3})
```

can I omit `new` operator? it seems to work without it as well..

Comment: If the documentation doesn't explicitly say you don't need `new`, and *does* show examples using `new`, then you need it. It may or may not work without (depending on implementation) in any given release, but that doesn't mean it will on the *next* release. The contract is defined by the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in the current version, you can omit it. If you look into the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/d2537c70843a838ec06cfc83d6e8e470be6d82cf/src/Record.js#L27-L29), there is a check that makes sure `this` is correctly bound if you are omitting `new`.

Answer (score 1):

It is unsafe to omit it, you might encounter problems in future versions. You can easily test whether a given version of Immutable.js supports this feature, like this:

```
typeof (Record({})) === "function"
```